# How to runtime link "plugin" reference dlls

Tags: c#, wpf, dll, reference, runtime

I am afraid this is a too broad question. But I still have not a clue as to how start this job so even a clue would help since nothing came out from googling...

Whenever I link a reference I add it before building it.
What I'd need is to be able to add whatever reference is added in a dir.
That would allow me to put a dll in a dir and add it AT RUNTIME ONLY if that dll is present.

So say

- that nothing is added at start ---> no additional features.
- I add 1.dll ----> the features present in 1.dll shall be added
- I add 2.dll ----> the features present in 2.dll shall be added

and so on...

I call those dlls plugin since they are similar to plugins.

Thank you in advance for your help.
Patrick

Comment: What have you tried so far? Assuming your 1.dll and 2.dll are implementing same contract to support a plugin infrastructure. This can be achieved by many ways. You can use Raw reflection to load and invoke assemblies or use frameworks like [MEF](https://mef.codeplex.com/). There are plenty of articles and samples to implement what you are asking.

Comment: oh yes, I forgot about the MEF Framework when typing my answer. That would probably be the easier solution.

Comment: My bad I have tried ... nothing since this is completely outside my knowledge (and I am new to wpf too). As I said I have googled for various keywords. But my search didn't bring anything. But thanks for you comment! Now I have something to start from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a new [AppDomain](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.appdomain(v=vs.110).aspx) and set the appRelativeSearchPath to your plugin folder. Then you are able to load the additional assemblies using the Load method of your new AppDomain.

If you want to access classes from the new AppDomain in your applications main AppDomain you can instantiate them using the [CreateInstanceAndUnwrap](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3c4f1xde.aspx) method of AppDomain. But the classes in your plugin assemblies have to inherit [MarshalRefObject](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.marshalbyrefobject(v=vs.110).aspx) for this to work.

I hope this points you into the right direction.